# Unique contraints per user

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto, unique-constraint

Consider the following `changeset`:

```
defmodule Flashcards.Cards.Deck do
  use Ecto.Schema
  import Ecto.Changeset


  schema "decks" do
    field :name, :string
    field :user_id, :id

    timestamps()
  end

  @doc false
  def changeset(deck, attrs) do
    deck
    |> cast(attrs, [:name, :user_id])
    |> validate_required([:name])
    |> unique_constraint(:name)
  end
end
```

The `unique_constraint` (along with the `unique_index` in the migration) makes the `name` field unique *across all users*.

In practice, however, I want to make the `name` field unique *per user* - what is the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add

```
create index(:decks, [:user_id, :name], unique: true)
```

to your migration file

Comment: Thanks! I think  the`name` argument to `index` has type `atom`: https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/2.0.1/Ecto.Migration.Index.html

Comment: Should probably mention that `unique_constraint(:name)` will not work anymore.
`unique_constraint(name: decks_user_id_name_index)` should do if no custom index name is provided

Comment: Thanks, I used `unique_constraint(:name, [name: :decks_user_id_name_index])`.